# Simple interpreter using Haskell

Tags: haskell, interpreter, abstract-syntax-tree

I am still learning Haskell and the question seems very basic but it's been stomping me for a while.

Given the following

```
data Term =
    Number Integer
  | Abs Term
  | Plus Term Term
  | Mult Term Term
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I want to create an interpreter such that if I call, for example,

```
evaluate (Plus (Number 10) (Number 10))
```

it will return 20. Below is what I have so far

```
myabsolute :: Integer -> Integer
myabsolute n = if n >= 0 then n else -n

evaluate :: Term -> Integer
evaluate Plus = evaluate(t1) + evaluate(t2)
evaluate Mult = evaluate(t1) * evaluate(t2)
evaluate Abs = myabs(evaluate(t1))
evaluate _ = 0
```

I am confused how to get the **`Number Integer`** part working since I do not know how to extract the numbers and map them to `t1` and `t2` in `Plus`, `Mult`, and `Abs`.

Since I am still learning, if I am doing something completely wrong please let me know!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how the `Plus` case would work:

```
evaluate :: Term -> Integer
evaluate (Plus t1 t2) = evaluate t1 + evaluate t2
...
```

The `Plus` constructor has two terms, so we need two names in the pattern (`t1` and `t2`). In this case both `t1` and `t2` will be values of type `Term` which is why the expressions `evaluate t1` and `evaluate t2` make sense.

The `Number` constructor, however, only has one parameter, e.g. `Number 3`, so its case will look like:

```
evaluate (Number x) = ...use x here...
```

Here the variable `x` will have type `Integer`.

Comment: thanks for the help! Right now I got my plus, mult, and number working. For some reason my abs is giving mean " Equations for ‘evaluate’ have different numbers of arguments " error, do you know what the problem is? I've updated evaluate Abs t1 = myabs(evaluate(t1))